# How to create scroll bar that fits all images in one line without overflowing to line below

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and trying to figure this out but, I was wondering if there is a way to display an array of images horizontally without the images dropping to the line below and without the entire page moving with the scroll bar. Currently I have a div container with 5 images. I'd like to add more, however upon adding the 5th image to my div container the image dropped to line below my other 4 images.
With only 4 images, the page runs exactly how I want with a scroll bar that moves when you hover and doesn't move the entire webpage with it.

I looked up different solutions and tried adding white-space: no wrap and adjusting the width of my div container but none of these issues fixed the image dropping to the line below. With increasing the width of my div container I found that the entire webpage also moves with that div which is something I also don't want.

Attached is my code for HMTL and CSS

```css
.menu_imagebox {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
       
        <title>TOWN_Restaurant</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description"content="TOWN is a fine dining Asian cuisine restaurant whose mission is to bring quality, style, and good fortune to all guests. ">
        <meta name="keywords" content="TOWN Restaurant, food, story, menus, contact, location">
        <meta name="author" content="Alexandria Brown">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7d95d78745.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="menu_page">
                        <div class="food">
                                <h2>Cuisine Menu</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu_container">
                                <img alt="menu" class="menu" src="images/menu_pg1.jpg">

                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="menu_imagebox">
                        <div class="menu_image1">
                                <img atl="" class="" src="images/salmon.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu_image2">
                                <img alt="" class="" src="images/app.jpg">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="menu_image3">
                                <img alt="" class="" src="images/chicken.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu_image4"></div>
                                <img alt="" class="" src="images/app2jpg.jpg">

                        </div>
                        <div class="menu_image5"></div>
                                <img alt="" class="" src="images/wagyu.jpg">

                        </div>
                        <div class="menu_image6"></div>
                                <img alt="" class="" src="">

                        </div>
                       


                </div>
```

Comment: You can take inspiration from https://codepen.io/therizaldev/pen/JjKQGXN

Comment: @Servesh Chaturvedi Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put Everything You want to Scroll in this Div i.e images then only the images will scroll left and right while the rest of the page remains still.

```
<div class="hscroll"></div>

<style>
.hscroll {
    overflow-x: auto; /* Horizontal */
  }
</style>
```

Also, you should arrange the images in a table and read more about semantic markup.